# How to make the Reward Name bold here?

Tags: php

https://gyazo.com/1ea9770a239a2cac28f0003ee014ba72

https://gyazo.com/733ec50b93a77000c7593e6e5030725d

I would like to make "James Bond" be shown in bold, unsure where to put   elements? Cheers!

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Instead, paste the code into the question and format it as a code block. It's both faster for you and much more convenient for us. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this many ways, but since you mention elements it would be easiest to wrap the two reward title lines in `<strong>` tags.

`<strong><?= e(get($reward, "title")) ?></strong>`

Answer (score 0):

Make a div for the title of the image and add a class to make it bold.

You can do something like this

```css
.test1
{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.test2
{
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
Title (James)
</div>

<div class="test2">
Title (James)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to pu a comment.
That should do it:

```
<b><?php= e(get($reward, title)); ?></b>
```